# docker: Variables in two stage build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am using a two stage build for a docker image;

I want to make a value in my second stage configurable, so I was thinking of using `ARG`.

However I am not sure the `--build-arg` command line option applies to other than the first stage, so I came up with this

```
### First stage
FROM some_base_image

ARG MYUSERNAME=foo

### Second stage
FROM another_base_image

ARG MYUSERNAME=$MYUSERNAME
```

but that didn't work;

any suggestions how to pass via the `build` command line some `--build-arg`s that should be usable from the second stage?

Answer (score 0):

ARG instructions have a scope, it's described here in the docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#scope

> An ARG instruction goes out of scope at the end of the build stage where it was defined. To use an arg in multiple stages, each stage must include the ARG instruction.

So you can use an ARG in multiple stages, you just need to use the `ARG` instruction again as shown in the example:

```
FROM busybox
ARG SETTINGS
RUN ./run/setup $SETTINGS

FROM busybox
ARG SETTINGS
RUN ./run/other $SETTINGS
```